# php prevent foreach in foreach double

Tags: php, date, foreach, between

I am tryig to get dates between from and to date. By using the datetime class
it works fine however when I use it with dynamic result, such as foreach inside foreach the dates is being doubled. I have tried using unique_array but with no luck. Any suggestions? :)

Availabledates content screenshot (ignore the comma):

[image]

Example:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT fdate, tdate FROM availabledates');
    foreach($result as $data):
        $fdate = date('Y-m-d', $data->fdate);
        $tdate = date('Y-m-d', $data->tdate);

        $begin = new DateTime($fdate);
        $end = new DateTime($tdate);

        $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
        foreach($daterange as $date){
            echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
        }
    endforeach;
```

[Link to fiddle](http://viper-7.com/6ZcNu8)

Comment: Are there multiple rows in the `availabledates` table?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing the error (with hard-coded values instead of pulling from a database, but still seems like the output would be similar.) Can you describe in more detail how the output is doubled? Does each date print twice in a row, i.e. `2015-06-30, 2015-06-30, 2015-07-01, 2015-07-01, etc.`, or does the entire set of dates print twice?

Comment: Hmm.. Basically it is just messing up the order. I think the best explain is that it is dublicating the content. I do not think foreach inside foreach is the best solution, maybe there is a another solution? :)

Comment: Well, I may be misunderstanding the output, but I would expect some of the values to be repeated, because the date ranges for the two records do overlap. The first one is 6/30 to 8/23, and the second one is 8/3 to 8/16, and with the nested foreach loops the way you have them, it will output all the dates for the first record, then all the dates for the second record.

Comment: What is the goal with the output, actually?

Comment: I have added a fiddle :-) Goal is to get only the dates between wanted dates and not any double content :)

Answer (score 0):

Well. I don't know what to feel -.-. I found out that the range was so big that I thought it was a bug. Turned out it was not. It had a range of 40 days. I should have paid more attention. Thanks for your time: Don't panic :)